# Погрузка статей в реальном времени wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

На сайте есть два селекта, в первом селекте нужно выбрать рубрику, и как только мы выбрали рубрику сразу все записи из этой рубрики должны подгружаться во второй селект, во втором селекте при выборе записи, нажимаем кнопку показать и снизу должен отображаться контент статьи. Еще когда допустим мы выбрали случайно не ту рубрику, то если мы в первом селекте поменяем рубрику на другую(не на ту которую выбрали первый раз) то и во втором селекте должны быть записи только с выбранной рубрики.

Начал это все реализовывать, методом проб и ошибок, пришел к одной мысле, когда выбираю в первом селекте рубрику, ее айди передается ajax запросом в файл filter.php потом хотел в этом файле сделать выгрузку по этому айди названия записей и вернуть обратно, но так как файл filter.php не есть вордпресовский, то такие циклы как WP_query и get_post он не видит.

В чем заключается вопрос:

1. Правильная ли у меня мысля, и смогу ли я добиться желаемых
   результатов;
2. Может есть другие варианты ?
3. И как мне все это организовать

p.s. Ниже прилагаю код который написал

Это страница самых селектов index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php if($browser == 'iphone'){ ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
    <?php } ?>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>" />
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<script>
$(function(){
 $('.delivery_list').click(function(){
 $(".cities_list").slideToggle('fast');
 });
 $('ul.cities_list li').click(function(){
 var tx = $(this).html();
 var tv = $(this).attr('alt');
 $(".cities_list").slideUp('fast');
 $(".delivery_list span").html(tx);
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wp-content/themes/testwp/filter_post/filter.php",
                data: "tv="+tv,
                success: function(data) {   
                    $('.cities_list2').append('<li>'+data+'</li>');
                }
        });
 });
 });
 $(function(){
 $('.delivery_list2').click(function(){
 $(".cities_list2").slideToggle('fast');
 });
 $('ul.cities_list2 li').click(function(){
 var tx = $(this).html();
 var tv = $(this).attr('alt');
 $(".cities_list2").slideUp('fast');
 $(".delivery_list2 span").html(tx);        
 });
 });        
</script>   
        <div class="delivery_block">                    
            <?php
            $kat = 3;
            $na_akran = '<ul class="cities_list">';
            $dochernii_kategorii = get_categories('child_of=' . $kat . '&hide_empty=0');
            foreach ($dochernii_kategorii as $dochernaya_kategoria) :
                if ($kat == $dochernaya_kategoria->category_parent) :
                    $id_from_cat = get_cat_ID($dochernaya_kategoria->cat_name);
                    $na_akran .= '<li alt="' . $id_from_cat . '">';
                    $na_akran .= $dochernaya_kategoria->cat_name;
                    $na_akran .= '</li>';
                endif;
            endforeach;
            $na_akran .= '</ul>';
            print $na_akran;
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="delivery_list">
            <div id="btn"></div>
            <span>Рубрика</span>
            <div class="delivery_text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="delivery_block2">                   
            <ul class="cities_list2">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="delivery_list2">
            <div id="btn2"></div>
            <span>Запись</span>
            <div class="delivery_text2"></div>
        </div>      
    </div><!-- wrapper -->
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Это файл filter.php который принимает айди рубрики с первого селекта

```
<?php 
$tv = $_POST['tv']; 
$pageid = $tv;
$the_query = new WP_Query('cat='.$tv.'&showposts=3&orderby=desc'); while  ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
the_title();
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
$about = get_post($pageid);
echo $the_query;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика у вас правильная. Вопрос в том как `filter.php` прикрутить к WordPress

Есть несколько способов.

1) Считается плохим (как минимум из-за того что `wp-load.php` вызывается два раза). В `filter.php` прописать

```
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
```

2) Получше. Оформить `filter.php` как плагин Wordpress, чтобы файл был в эко-системе Wordpress. Подробнее про создание плагина можно прочесть [здесь](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

3) Самый правильный. Воспользоваться встроенным ajax-механизмом. Суть в том, что обращаясь к `ajax-admin.php` вы можете доставать какие угодно данные простым способом.

Обратите внимание на `myaction`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:ajaxurl,
    data:'action=myaction&input_val=' + my_value,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery('#response').html(data);
    }
});
```

`functions.php`:

```
function true_function(){
    $new_posts = get_posts(array('cat'=>$_POST['input_val']));
    $options = '';
    foreach ($new_posts as $new_post) {
        $options .= '<option>'.$new_post['post_title'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $options;
}

// wp_ajax_ - только для зарегистрированных пользователей
add_action('wp_ajax_myaction', 'true_function'); // wp_ajax_{значение параметра action}

// wp_ajax_nopriv_ - только для незарегистрированных, т е для залогиненных он работать не будет (результатом выполнения запроса будет 0)
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'true_function'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{значение параметра action}
```

Более развернутая статья - http://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/admin-ajax.html

Comment: решил использовать первый вариант, вроде работает сверху выводит названия статей, но снизу выбивает ошибку "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to string in W:\domains\testwp.com\wp-content\themes\testwp\filter_post\filter.php on line 9" я так понимаю оно не может конвертировать WP_Query в строку $the_query, как быть?

Comment: использовал вместо wp_query цикл get_post все отлично выводит, но проблема уже в том что оно выводит все в одну строчку, так еще в конце добавляет Array

Comment: `echo $the_query;` - на это ругается? зачем это? удалить

Comment: все отлично выводит заголовки как нужно, большое спасибо) теперь вопрос в другом  http://pastenow.ru/E2E6 оно выводит все строчку, а мне нужно чтобы каждый заголовок был в заключен в <li>

Comment: все сделал, и последняя проблема, как сделать так чтобы при выборе другой рубрики все записи во втором селекте убирались и были только с выбранной рубрики?

Comment: `the_title();` -> `echo '<li>'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'</li>'`;

Comment: `$('.cities_list2').html(data);` то есть `append` заменить на `html`

Comment: и отметьте, пожалуйста, этот ответ как правильный.

Comment: большое СПАСИБО вам, я уже неделю играюсь и не знал как сделать.

Comment: последний вопрос, все работает отлично, теперь во втором селекте передаю айди выбранного поста только уже в файл filter-post.php(они одинаковые с filter.php только переменные другие), а как мне по ид поста выгрузить его контент ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9668/77447

Comment: спасибо Вам еще раз) вы очень помогли мне))) дайте мне ваши контактные данные пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в начало файла filter.php строку

```
require( 'ПУТЬ_ДО_ФАЙЛА_wp-load.php' );
```

Это должно решить проблему подключения к функциям WordPress